# Use JavaScript/jQuery to change linear gradient percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gradient

I have a page with a linear gradient in the wrapper element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS is:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) 60%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%); /* Safari 5.1 - 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) 60%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.1 - 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) 60%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%); /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) 60%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%);
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

The gradient shows up ok on its own. However, I want to use js/jquery to change the gradient as I scroll down the page. I don't think the current js code is affecting anything at the moment. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var topDis = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("#wrapper").css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) " + (60 - topDis/100) + "%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%);");
        $("#wrapper").css("background", "-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) " + (60 - topDis/100) + "%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%);")
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the semicolon before the closing quote.

```
$("#wrapper").css("background", "-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) " + (60 - topDis/100) + "%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%);")
```

It should look like this:

```
$("#wrapper").css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) " + (60 - topDis/100) + "%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%)")
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved without Javascript/jQuery. Simply by using CSS. Below is the example.

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;  /* height has to be defined for scrolling */
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
  }
```

```html
<h1>Change Background Gradient on Scroll</h1>

<h2>Linear Gradient - Top to Bottom</h2>
<p>This linear gradient starts at the top. It starts green, transitioning to blue.</p>

<h2 style="position:fixed;">Scroll to see the effect.</h2>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I think this is a different effect from what I'm trying to achieve. first of all, the height of my document can't be fixed, because it's a template for different pages. second, I want the middle stops of the gradient to change based on the scroll, as opposed to being static.